# I want to display something after 24 hours in php how?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to display something after 24 hour. How can I do that? The first date is saved in a database and the other I will get at run time. But what will be the formula to calculate these 24 hours?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html and http://www.php.net/datetime -1 for lack of reasearch effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the date difference:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(?, dateCol) <= 1 THEN 'go'
        ELSE 'no go'
    END CASE AS go_Or_No_Go
FROM yourtable 
WHERE <parameters here to get the date value you seek for in the db>
```

The `?` could be `CURRENT_DATE` or other date functions, depending on what date type you've stored in your db as listed here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If you're up for speed you can compare this as an embedded SQL command, function, or stored procedure to see which runs fastest, seeing that the SQL is quite static in that it requires no parameter and does not need any further interpretation from PHP other than checking if `go_Or_No_Go` is equal to `go` or `no go` -- Which you can even change to 1 or 0, or any 2 different values like:

```sql
WHEN DATEDIFF(?, dateCol) <= 1 THEN 1 -- or 'YES'
ELSE 0 -- or 'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from foo WHERE datetime_column < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```